# Obtaining SSL Certificate from Let's Encrypt While ISP Blocks Port 80

Tags: apache-http-server, port-forwarding, ssl, certificate, isp

Currently I'm running an apache http server listening on port 81 since my ISP blocks port 80. I'd like to obtain a valid ssl certificate and I've been reading this forum [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/port-80-and-443-blocked-by-isp-how-to-authenticate-domain/13065), but I don't entirely understand what they are talking about. I have full control over my router and my server. So, is there any way to obtain a ssl certificate from Let's Encrypt with my setup?

I want to run the https on port 443.

I also can't do the txt verification as I don't have full control over my dns yet.

When I try to run `sudo certbot --apache` I get this:

```
Cleaning up challenges
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently 
needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain.
Please add a virtual host for port 80.
```

Comment: Submit the relevant information from the shell script which mentions the port.  Software recommendations are entirely out of scope.  We will not make recommendations.  Your question is about Let’s Encrypt.  That’s within scope a recommendation is not within scope

Answer (score 2):

The main question is what port will you be using for HTTPS (assuming that 81 is HTTP)

### HTTPS Will be on port 443

Some ISPs will block 80, but not 443. In this case you should be able to use any of the normal clients and challenge types

### HTTPS will be on some other port (not 443)

In this case, we will want to use the `dns-01` challenge, something like this:

```
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d mydomain.com
```

Note that this will require you to create a `TXT` record with specified contents, so you will need to have control of your DNS.

Comment: I was going to have it on port 443, but it keeps saying there is an error with it trying to fetch validation info. I also have full control over my DNS

Comment: @Erik have you verified that your ISP is not blocking port 443? You could either configure Apache with a self-signed certificate or try HTTP over port 443 after configuring Apache to listen on it.

Comment: I've already verified that my ISP is not blocking port 443. I used to have a web site listening on port 443.

Comment: Could it be that I am using no ip for my DNS name? I've read somewhere that they allow it, but recently I read a different source contradicting this. Is this true?

Comment: you can no longer create a new (non-renewed) cert if you only have port 443 access